# Is qTesla Secure?

Tags: public-key, signature, post-quantum-cryptography, nist, ring-lwe

qTesla is a signature scheme and a submission to the NIST post-quantum standardization process, which made it to the second round. It is based on the hardness of RLWE. The NIST [round 2 status report](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ir/2020/NIST.IR.8309.pdf) says that it didn't make it to round 3 because:

> the
> performance of the remaining parameter sets of qTESLA is not strong enough to remain
> competitive. In particular, the public key sizes of q-TESLA-p-I and q-TESLA-p-III are about 15
> to 20 times as large as those of FALCON and CRYSTALS-DILITHIUM, and the signature sizes
> are larger as well.

However, there were also attacks on the scheme, notably [one by Lyubashevsky and Schwabe](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography/documents/round-2/official-comments/qTESLA-round2-official-comment.pdf); the document states that

> We (Peter Schwabe and I) give a complete break of (3) ‐ in particular, a signing algorithm for arbitrary messages that
> doesn't require the use of the secret key and is faster than the qTesla signing algorithm (which uses the secret
> keys).

So my question is: is qTesla considered secure? Was this attack just an attack on a variant of qTesla, or did it render qTesla insecure? Was this attack a factor in NIST not progressing it to round 3?

Comment: That will depend on what you define qTestla to be, and to a lesser degree what you take as "secure". A proposed variant/mode is not secure at all, and 10 out of 12 of the proposed parameters were questionable enough to be retracted.

Comment: Is there a form which is unbroken ***and*** has a reliable parameter set?